# Why would the Jews dwell in booths specifically while fighting Sichon and Og?

Tags: sukkah, sukkot, aharon

The **Rokeach** § 219 (brought by **Eliyah Rabbah** 625:1) brings those who say that when Rabbi Akiva (**Sukkah** 11b) says that *Sukkos* commemorates the *sukkos* that the Jews dwelled in, it's referring to when they fought against Sichon and Og ([**Numbers** 21:21-35](http://sefaria.org/Numbers.21.21-35)).

**Eliyah Rabbah** (basically the same as what the **Rokeach** himself writes):

> והרוקח הלכות סוכה סי' ריט כתכ כשצלו על ארץ סיחון ועוג ועל כרכים שבארץ כנען **אז** ישבו בסוכות, וזה 'למען ידעו וכו''‏

It sounds like the time that they lived in *sukkos* was specifically while fighting Sichon and Og (or at least it **started** at that time).

Why would this be? In general I would ask why would they be in *sukkos* if they had the Clouds of Glory protecting them (which everyone agrees with, just Rabbi Akiva says that's not what the holiday of *Sukkos* commemorates). But assuming they were dwelling in *sukkos*, why was it only during this time period?

My only guess is when Aharon died, the clouds dissipated (*inter alia* [**Rosh Hashanah** 3a](https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.3a.1?lang=bi) (brought by [**Rashi**](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.21.1?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.21.1.1&lang2=bi) to [**Numbers** 21:1](http://sefaria.org/Numbers.21.1)), [**Taanis** 9a](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.9a.10?lang=bi)). That's when they needed to build shelters. **Ta'anis** says that the Clouds of Glory returned in the merit of Moshe. It doesn't say when. Perhaps it was after they fought Sichon and Og (which happened seemingly soon after Aharon died ([**Numbers** 20:22-29](http://sefaria.org/Numbers.20.22-29)).

Does anyone explain this Rokeach?

Comment: "But assuming they were dwelling in sukkos, why was it only during this time period?" I don't see from your paraphrase that it _was_ only at that time. Maybe they were in booths other times, too, but only the ones from that time are commemorated.

Comment: Note: **Gilyonei HaShas** to **Sukkah** 11b s.v. ענני הכבוד understood the **Rokeach** to be saying that the Jews dwelled in *sukkos* during their seven-year conquest of the land of Israel. According to him, this question doesn't start (as they didn't have the Clouds of Glory in the land of Israel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chasam Sofer [in his Torah commentary](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21620&st=&pgnum=116) and [Responsa (O.C. 185)](https://www.sefaria.org/Responsa_Chatam_Sofer%2C_Orach_Chayim.185.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explains that the army left the camp in order to wage war and was thus no longer surrounded by the Clouds of Glory. The Sukkah commemorates entering the land of Israel, which commenced with these battles fought by soldiers who needed the shelter of physical booths. See the commentary for a further explanation of how the two opinions in the Gemarah are actually closely related to each other based on this understanding.

It seems to me that the Chasam Sofer's explanation is indicated by [the Rokeach himself](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49371&st=&pgnum=95) who quotes the verse from Shmuel 2 11:11:

> וַיֹּ֨אמֶר אוּרִיָּ֜ה אֶל־דָּוִ֗ד הָ֠אָרוֹן וְיִשְׂרָאֵ֨ל וִֽיהוּדָ֜ה
>   יֹשְׁבִ֣ים בַּסֻּכּ֗וֹת

and explains that they would use booths for shelter in the fields until the war was won.